# How do i have a .csproj build a .proj file before building itself?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a .csproj file and a .proj file.  As part of my .proj file I am generating a file to include in the .csproj, so the .proj needs to run first.

How can this be done.  I originally tried to add a project reference as follows:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\FileGenerator\FileGenerator.proj">
  <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly> 
</ProjectReference>
```

This however gives me the error:

error MSB4057: The target "GetNativeManifest" does not exist in the project

I then noticed there is a BeforeBuild target in my csproj file.

Can I use this to have the other file be built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MSBuild` task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) to invoke other projects. Example:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="..\FileGenerator\FileGenerator.proj" Targets="Build" />
</Target>
```

If you need any cleanup done as part of the common `Clean` target, you can plug in custom cleanup target like this:

```
<Target Name="FileGeneratorClean" BeforeTargets="Clean">
    <MSBuild Projects="..\FileGenerator\FileGenerator.proj" Targets="Clean" />
</Target>
```